# Running an installed app already paid for on an account not logged in

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I have an app I paid for on another mac under my Apple ID. Can I log into a different mac with the same Apple ID and install it, then log out with the app still working?

Comment: That all depends on the application and how it's been developed.  Have you asked the developer of the application in question?

Comment: @fsb it's Logic Pro X

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to remain logged in to Mac App Store to use an app installed from there.

You may be asked for your Apple ID password which was used to purchase the app when installing an update.

Comment: Is that the OPs question (remaining logged into the MAS)?  I read it as they wanted to know if they could install an app using one Apple ID, log out, log in with a different ID, and have that app still function correctly.  Maybe I'm wrong so hopefully the OP will clarify their question.